# I have 1 million+ records in my database. How to paginate it faster..?

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

I have 1 million+ records in database.

On the index page, multiple filter to filter through database create where clause.
eg

**select * from primaryinfo where category='abc' and technology='PQR'**

I want to show--:
1. number of records found
2. pages.
3. 10 out 100(kind of thing) on the page.

Am sending the filtered records as json object to jquery, am looping through the records and appending to a particular div.

below is my php pagination code

```
$selectQ = "select * from primaryinfo where  match(title,description,tags)       against('".$searchCombine."') and category='abc' and technology='pqr'";
$result = mysql_query($selectQ);
$total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
$total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);
$start;
$end;
if (isset($_POST['pagecc']))
{
$show_page = $_POST['pagecc'];  
if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
{
    $start = ($show_page - 1) * $per_page;
    $end = $start + $per_page;
} else
{ 
        $start = 0;              
    $end = $per_page;
}
 }
else
{ 
$start = 0;
$end = $per_page;
} 
if($end > $total_results)
    $end = $total_results; 
for($i=$start;$i<$end;$i++){
// here the json object is created
}
```

Comment: Use the `LIMIT` clause in MYSQL.

Comment: I would separately count all records with COUNT(*) and then only select the as much as you need for the page currently viewing:
(LIMIT $page*$rowsPerPage, $rowsPerPage).

Comment: if I use LIMIT, i ll not be able to get total records found...which I want to show on the page

Comment: And please... stop using `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: could you post some example or link which I could refer..

Comment: You can use `COUNT(*)` to get total records found, but you only need `LIMIT` to show pagination.

Comment: Searching to specific values with `WHERE` should help alot, and that `LIMIT` clause too. I saw some performance statistics between using MySQL and MySQLi, and MySQLi were sometimes around 3 times faster as MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can get the total:

```
select COUNT(*) from primaryinfo 
where  match(title,description,tags) against('searchCombine') 
       and category='abc' 
       and technology='pqr'
```

Then you can paginate using the `LIMIT` feature:

```
select * from primaryinfo 
where  match(title,description,tags) against('searchCombine') 
       and category='abc' 
       and technology='pqr' 
LIMIT 0 10; -- Start at offset 0 show ten items per page
```

Please note that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed in a future PHP version. Please consider using `mysqli` or `PDO`.

To further improve performance you could look at setting up indexes on columns. Particularly the category and technology columns but this will depend on your data.

Comment: Thanks Jim. ll try your example right now...yeah I have created index on category and technology columns..

Comment: i tried..working good...but i thing my internet is having some problem..but it worked for me..Thanks @Jim